# Strings == operator compares refrences or not?

Tags: java, string

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a="meow";
        String b=a+"deal";
        String c="meowdeal";
        System.out.println(b==c);
    }
}
```

According to me == operators compares refrences . So b==c should print "true"
But it prints "false" . I checked by printing hashcode of "b"and "c" .

Hashcode of both are same

Comment: The hashcodes of strings are based on the _content_, like `equals`, not the _references_, like `==` .

Comment: *According to me == operators compares refrences* then why are you using it to compare values?

Comment: *According to me == operators compare references* and it does.  `b` and `c` refer to completely different objects.

Comment: You are correct that the `==` operators compares refrences. You are not setting `c` to refer to the same string object as `b`. So `b == c` should return false. Which it seems it does.

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares references, but the reference to `b` and `c` are different - they're two different `String` instances although the contain the same content.

If you want to compare the content of both Strings, use `equals()`.

Comment: If refrences are different, how come hashcode of both are sa

Comment: Hashcode is calculated on the content of the strings.

Comment: The `hashCode()` is based on the content of the Strings, not their reference.

Answer (score 1):

> According to me == operators compares refrences .

That is correct.  The `==` operator compares references if both operands are reference types.  (It is not correct if either operand is a primitive type ... but that's a different topic.)

> So b==c should print "true" But it prints "false" . I checked by printing hashcode of "b"and "c" .

Your reasoning is incorrect.

```
   String a = "meow";
   String b = a + "deal";
   String c = "meowdeal";
```

In fact, when that code has finished `b` and `c` refer to different string objects that have the same value.  In fact, the JLS states that the `+` operator creates a new string objext ... *unless* the expression is a constant expression.  (And it doesn't qualify as a constant expression in this case, because `a` is a variable.)

So `b == c` is `false` ... BECAUSE `==` is comparing references, and the references are different.

Comment: If refrences are different how come hashcode of both are same?

Comment: The hashcodes of strings are based on the string's value, NOT on its identity (reference).  Read the javadoc for `String.hashCode()`

Comment: Hashcode is calculated on the content of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `b.equals(c)` for objects and `==` for primitive types